# Convert datetime and divide into 2 column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm working in a SQL table which contains a column called `'DATETIME'` and it contains values like `'201701011730'`. The first 8 character is the date and last 4 characters is the time. Now I need to create a column called `'TIME'` and also a column called `'DATE'` to replace `'DATETIME'`. The example has shown below:

```
DATETIME(201701011730)--> DATE(20170101) and TIME(1730)
```

I'm trying to work with a update statement with CONVERT function but it doesn't worked. Is there any suggestion to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your combined column is called `dattimCol` you can do the following:

```
select convert(date, left(dattimCol,8)) [date],
       convert(time, stuff(substring(dattimCol,9,4),3,0,':')) [time]
from yourTable;
```

It is important to insert the ':' into the time-string before converting it.

As an update statement this transforms to:

```
update yourTable SET 
       dateCol=convert(date, left(dattimCol,8)),
       timeCol=convert(time, stuff(substring(dattimCol,9,4),3,0,':'));
```

OK, here are some short explanations, first [substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
substring(dattimCol,9,4)
```

(I could have used `right(dattimCol,4)` instead) will get us the 4 last digits of the datetime string representing the time of day ("1730"). I then "stuff" a colon (":") in the middle of that resultant string by using the [stuff()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/ms188043.aspx) function (available since at least SQL-server 2005)

```
stuff( sourceString, beginInsertionAtPosition, countOfCharsToDelete, insertionString )
```

Comment: I think this method is quite good, but i still have a question. Could you please help to explain the meaning of the value 4, 3 and 0into the convert(time, stuff(substring(dattimCol,9,4),3,0,':')) ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
CREATE  TABLE DATES(DATETIME VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO DATES VALUES('201701011730')
INSERT INTO DATES VALUES('201801011740')
SELECT * FROM DATES
ALTER TABLE DATES ADD [DATE] VARCHAR(8)
ALTER TABLE DATES ADD [TIME] VARCHAR(4)

DECLARE @DATETIME VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DATETIME FROM DATES
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DATETIME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
UPDATE DATES SET DATE=(SELECT SUBSTRING(DATETIME,0,9) FROM DATES WHERE DATETIME=@DATETIME) WHERE DATETIME=@DATETIME
UPDATE DATES SET TIME=(SELECT SUBSTRING(DATETIME,9,LEN(DATETIME)) FROM DATES WHERE DATETIME=@DATETIME) WHERE DATETIME=@DATETIME
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DATETIME
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C

SELECT * FROM DATES
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a `CURSOR`. One should avoid cursors if ever possible (rare exceptions exist)...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code for showing the example you can use the below code

```
Create Table #ABC(T1 NVARCHAR(500),date nvarchar(255),Time nvarchar(255))
  Insert Into #ABC(T1) Values ('201701011730')

 Update #ABC
 SET date=SUBSTRING(T1,0,9), Time=SUBSTRING(T1,9,LEN(t1))
```

I think you are using string format rather then date and time format for more information you can go to the following links

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: SQL Server will be able to cast an unseparated date string of `yyyymmdd`, but not an unseparated time like `HHmm`. You'll have to insert the `:` to get a proper time. Further more `SUBSTRING` starts at `1`, the length should be `8` and cutting from the start is better done with `LEFT`... Okay, this was `</wisenheimer>`-mode :-)

Comment: I know but Its not mentioned in the question that we need to insert : in the time so that is why i have not used it.

Answer (score 0):

-----Declare  @datetime_str variable where set datetime in string format

```
Declare @datetime_str varchar(20);
set @datetime_str='201701011730';
select SUBSTRING(@datetime_str,0,9) as date, SUBSTRING(@datetime_str,9,12) as time
```

--------------------or-------------------

```
select SUBSTRING('201701011730',0,9) as date, SUBSTRING('201701011730',9,12) as time
```